# Converting JavaScript callback function to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code for my Google Extension:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            from: 'popup',
            subject: 'Import'
        }, ShowResult);
    });
});

function ShowResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

Is it possible to convert this code into jQuery? I'm not sure what's `chrome.tabs.*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            from: 'popup',
            subject: 'Import'
        }, ShowResult);
    });
});

function ShowResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: It worked! I think I tried this, except that I put the ShowResult inside the jQuery. Thanks a lot!